# What does "contained continuously" mean? As in, "metric space $X$ is contained continuously in metric space $Y$".

Tags: analysis, continuity, metric-spaces, terminology, hilbert-spaces

What we mean by the "Contained continuously" terminology?!

> Definition: Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and $E$ is an open bounded subset of $\mathbb[C]$. The Hilbert space of measurable functions g in $L^{2}(E,H)$, where g is analytic in E, is called the Bergman Space for $E$.

*Where $L^{2}(E,H)$ is a space of all measurable functions $g:E \to H$, where $$\Vert g \Vert_{2,E} =\{ \int \Vert g(\lambda)d_{\mu}(\lambda)\}^{\frac{1}{2}} < \infty $$

> Definition : Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and $E$ is an open bounded subset of $\mathbb[C]$. and m $\ge$ 0 be a fixed nonzero integer. Then the space of all functions g in $L^{2}(E,H)$ whose partial derivatives to order $m$ also belongs to $L^{2}(E,H)$ is called the Vector valued Sobolev Space and denoted by $W^{m}(E,H)$, where it is endowed with the norm $$(\Vert g \Vert ^{2})_{m}=\sum_{j=0}^m (\Vert (\partial g)^{j}\Vert^{2})_{2,E}$$
> That is $W^{m}(E,H)$ is a Hilbert space **contained continuously** in $L^{2}(E,H)$.

Contained continuously, what does it mean?!

Comment: Where do you read this phrase from? My current guess is that it means that there exists a continuous embedding (i.e. continuous injective map) $f : X \to Y$.

Comment: Is it possible the phrase was _compactly contained_?

Comment: I have read it in the reference  ( Alzuraiqi, S. and Patel, A. (2010). On n-normal operators. Genral Mathematics Notes, 1(2): p(70) ) @Clement Yung

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang No it is written "Contained continuously" in the reference

Comment: In the present form, the question is unanswerable since the terminology is nonstandard. Consider quoting one or two paragraphs from the paper containing this terminology.

Comment: As suggested by @ClementYung, [here](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=0P8ICAAAQBAJ&pg=PA142&dq=%22contained+continuously%22&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiXz_KsufL3AhX4GrkGHXXsCrIQ6AF6BAgMEAM#v=onepage&q=%22contained%20continuously%22&f=false) it means [continuously embedded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_embedding).

Comment: Given the edit, the meaning of the passage is that the identity map $^m(,)\to L^2(E,H)$ is continuous.